# Vue - passing apollo query result from parent to child component

Tags: vuejs2, apollo

I have this parent component which makes a call to this apollo query:

```
<template>
        <div class="row" style="flex-wrap: nowrap; width:102%">
            <BusinessContextTeamPanel :business_contexts="business_contexts"></BusinessContextTeamPanel></BusinessContextTeamDetailPanel>
        </div>
</template>
    <script>
        apollo: {
                    business_contexts: {
                        query: gql`query ($businessContextId: uuid!) {
                           business_contexts(where: {id: {_eq: $businessContextId }}) {
                               id
                               businessContextTeams {
                                 id
                                 team {
                                   name
                                   id
                                 }
                                 role
                               }
                           }
                         }`,
                        variables: function() {
                            return {
                                businessContextId: this.currentContextId
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
    </script>
```

My child component( `BusinessContextTeamPanel`) takes the input props and uses it like this:

```
<template>
    <div v-if="business_contexts.length > 0">
        <div v-for="teams in business_contexts" :key="teams.id">
                        <div v-for="team in teams.businessContextTeams" :key="team.id" style="padding-top: 20px;min-width: 400px">
                            <div style="height: 25px; color: #83d6c0;">

                                <div style="width: 7%; font-size: 10px; float: left; padding-top: 8px; cursor: pointer;" class="fa fa-minus-circle" ></div>

                                <div style="width: 50%; float: left; padding-right: 10px;">
                                    <div class="gov-team-text" @click="editTeam(team)">{{ team.team.name }}</div>
                                </div>

                                <div style="width: auto; float: right;">
                                    <b-badge variant="light">{{ team.role }}</b-badge>
                                </div>
                                <div style="width: 45%; margin-left: 4%; float: right;">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="clear: both; margin-bottom: 15px;"></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

The `v-if` here throws

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

while the `v-for` works.
And when I'm trying to use the props in a child method(`loadData()`) which is called on child component mount hook, I get also `undefined`

```
<script>
    import Treeselect from '@riophae/vue-treeselect';
    import _ from "lodash";


    export default {
        name: "BusinessContextTeamPanel",
        components: { Treeselect },
        props: ['business_contexts'],
        data() {
            return {
                itemModel: {},
                allRoles: [],
                formTitle: "",
                filteredTeams: [],
                showNoTeamMsg: false
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.loadData();
        },
        methods: {
            loadData() {
                let roles = [];
                _.forEach(["Admin", "Contributor", "Owner", "Master", "Viewer", "User"], function (role) {
                    roles.push({id: role, label: role});
                });
                console.log(this.business_contexts); // here I get undefined
                this.allRoles = roles;
                this.showNoTeamMsg = this.business_contexts.length === 0;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your apollo query isn't working, or it isn't ready in time for the child component's attempted use of it.

For debugging, in the parent component's template add {{ business_contexts }}, just so you can eyeball it. This will confirm whether the query is working.

If the query is working, it could be that your child component is trying to access the data before it's ready. Change your v-if from

```
<div v-if="business_contexts.length > 0">
```

to

```
<div v-if="business_contexts && business_contexts.length > 0">
```

EDIT: better yet, change the parent component to not try to load the child at all, until the parent has the data:

```
<BusinessContextTeamPanel v-if="business_contexts" :business_contexts="business_contexts"></BusinessContextTeamPanel></BusinessContextTeamDetailPanel>
```

Comment: I can see in the parent the data from `{{ business_contexts }}` I can also see it from the child, but the `v-if` still raises the  length of undefined even with your change. How come the `v-for` below the v-if displays correctly the data from `business_contexts` but the v-if crashes?

Comment: Are you sure it's the v-if that's raising that error? The `&&` in the if statement that I provided makes it short-circuit - the part after && won't execute if the part before it doesn't evaluate as true. Therefore, if business_contexts is undefined, then it will not evaluate `business_contexts.length > 0`, and so that error message really should not be possible. Double check that the undefined error isn't now being thrown from somewhere else; your child component mounted() is also trying to access the variable before it's ready. I'll update my answer with more on this

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely it, your mounted() hook is going to run before the data is ready. You want to delay loading the component until it's ready. Or you have to engineer your child component to look for that data only after it exists - mounted() is too early. E.g., you could instead call loadData() from a watcher, or you could do away with loadData() entirely and instead make this.showNoTeamMsg and this.allRoles into computed properties. This means they'll also be reactive, yay

Comment: Yep your perfectly right, I went with the idea that the props will be loaded with data before the mounted of the child, good points about the watcher and the computed values, appreciate. But still bugs me how come the v-for renders correctly the data? Is it using like an async pipe?

Comment: No worries! Vue templates are still a bit magical to me, but my understanding is that they will reload upon changes to reactive variables. So even if there was an error, business_contexts later becomes available, the template reloads, and there's no longer an error at that point